# Group by registros

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, conjuntos

La pregunta que se me hace es: Número de hijos y número de empleados agrupados por hijos, mostrando sólo los grupos cuyo número de empleados sea mayor que 1.

```
mysql> select nombre, hijos from empleados;

 nombre                    | hijos

José Luis Pérez           |     2 |

Encarna Lopez Lopez       |     0 |

| Ines Montero Zafra        |     1 |

| Fernando Romero Días      |     1 |

| Rosa Lorite Lopez         |     0 |

| Manuel Lopez Marín        |     0 |

| Andrés Morales Martín     |     3 |

| Alfonso Gutierrez Lopez   |     1 |

| María Pascual Rojo        |     3 |

| Francisca Colate Gonzalez |     3 |

Lola Martinez Contreras   |     1
```

Yo entiendo que al hacer un group by hijos no se puede porque no coinciden los nombres y los resultados. Pero al hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
select count(nombre), count(hijos) from empleados group by hijos having count(nombre) >1;
```

el resultado es el siguiente:

```
mysql> select count(nombre), count(hijos) from empleados group by hijos having count(nombre) >1;

| count(nombre) | count(hijos) |


|             3 |            3 |

|             4 |            4 |

|             3 |            3 |
```

Como vemos antes, no hay nadie que tenga 4 hijos, ¿Qué me está devolviendo esta consulta?

Espero que se entiendan los registros, un saludo

Comment: No entiendo los votos negativos. Claramente se trata de una persona que lo ha intentado y ha compartido el código de sus intentos. Rubén, tu pregunta está bien planteada, continúa preguntando cuanto necesites...

Comment: Gracias David, la verdad es que no me salen registros así,  aún así gracias por el apoyo, un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu consulta te está devolviendo el número de empleados que tienen 0 hijos, que son 3, 1 hijo, que son 4, y así sucesivamente. El problema que estás teniendo es que no estás mostrando el campo por el que agrupas, sino en ambas columnas el número de registros de cada agrupamiento sin que sepas a qué grupo pertenece cada uno. Por eso te estás liando.

Prueba así y lo verás mucho más claro:

```
SELECT hijos n_hijos, COUNT(*) n_empleados
  FROM empleados
  GROUP BY hijos;
```

Obtendrás:

```
+---------+-------------+
| n_hijos | n_empleados |
+---------+-------------+
|       0 |           3 |
|       1 |           4 |
|       2 |           1 |
|       3 |           3 |
+---------+-------------+
```

Te paso el dataset con un formato más reproducible para las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE empleados(
  id_empleado int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31),
  hijos int
  );

INSERT INTO empleados (nombre, hijos) VALUES
('José Luis Pérez','2'),
('Encarna Lopez Lopez','0'),
('Ines Montero Zafra','1'),
('Fernando Romero Días','1'),
('Rosa Lorite Lopez','0'),
('Manuel Lopez Marín','0'),
('Andrés Morales Martín','3'),
('Alfonso Gutierrez Lopez','1'),
('María Pascual Rojo','3'),
('Francisca Colate Gonzalez','3'),
('Lola Martinez Contreras','1');
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias.